# network deployed in IBM cloud, but having an issue instantiating the chaincode

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I deployed a bna archive file to my ibm cloud instance. It has all the files you'd expect including the package.json. This was done following the tutorial here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/develop_starter.html#deploying-a-business-network

The last step in the process is a ping issued to ensure the network is up and running. I am getting an error telling me that the "chaincode is not instantiated".

I went to the web interface ( https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/network/myid ) and under **My Code / Install Code** section I can see my network. Under **Actions** there is an option to instantiate it on a peer. Clicking that gives me this error : *Unknown error occurred when instantiating chaincode, check your peer logs*.

Looking at the logs on the peer I can see this:

{"log":"npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/src/package.json'\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-06-19T13:20:48.455812355Z"}

That particular file IS part of my bna archive.

I can deploy the bna file to both my local composer-playground and also IBM's one ( https://blockchaindevelop.mybluemix.net/ ) and it works fine in both environments.

The same issue happens if I deploy the bna using the web interface, I simply can't instantiate it.

Any suggestions what I can do to get this network running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a software version issue.

The original documentation specified using composer 0.18.1 as the only one compatible with the IBM cloud infrastructure.

This has recently been updated to 0.19.x.

In the IBM cloud, I removed the original peer with all the old chaincode, removed the old certificate as well.

On my local machine I started from scratch:

- reinstalled latest composer,
- recreated the bna file

I then re-did all the steps as in the original documentation and this time everything worked and I managed to start the network and ping it.

Everything is up and running now. There was one last timeout issue when I tried to start the network, but I simply ran the command again and the problem went away.

Comment: I will ask the documentation team to get that changed. Thanks for letting us know!